# Spree Commerce : Where can I find customer newsletter subscribe flag in database?

Tags: spree

Can you tell me where can I find newsletter subscribe status in spree commerce table?

Regards,

Spree Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.17'
gem 'railties', '3.2.17'
gem 'netguru', git: 'git://github.com/netguru/netguru.git'
gem 'rabl'

# rabl needs to be before gon :/
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.13.4', require: false
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 2.17.7'
gem 'sidekiq-status'
#gem 'capistrano-sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-failures'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
gem 'draper', '= 0.15.0'
gem 'eco'
gem 'geoip', github: 'cjheath/geoip'
gem 'gon', '~> 4.0'
gem 'i18n-js', git: 'git://github.com/fnando/i18n-js.git'  #Pluralization bugs in offical version
gem 'js-routes'
gem 'konf'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'paperclip-remote'
gem 'pg'
gem 'proxylocal', require: false
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pry-remote'
gem 'rails-backbone'
gem 'sanitize'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'spreadsheet'

#gem 'spree_reviews', :github => 'spree/spree_reviews', :branch => '1-1-stable'
gem 'spree_reviews', :path => './spree_reviews'
gem 'to_xls'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem 'dropbox-api'
gem 'lazy_high_charts'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'elibri_watermarking'
gem 'elibri_api_client'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'refraction'
gem 'savon', '~> 2.0'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'openpayu'

# Forem
gem 'forem', git: 'git://github.com/radar/forem.git'
gem 'forem-theme-twist', git: 'git://github.com/radar/forem-theme-twist.git'
gem 'forem-markdown_formatter'

# Spree Ecommerce
gem 'spree', :github => "meal/spree", :branch => "1-1-stable"
gem 'spree_payu', path: './spree_payu'
gem 'spree_videos', git: 'git://github.com/iloveitaly/Spree-Videos.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'spree_localize', git: 'git://github.com/radar/spree_localize.git'
gem 'spree_product_groups', git: 'git://github.com/busiq/spree_product_groups.git'
gem 'spree_paypal_website_standard', git: 'git://github.com/meal/spree-pp-website-standard.git', branch: 'version112'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'spree_sunspot', github: 'jbrien/spree_sunspot_search'

# Omniauth
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'spree_social', git: 'git://github.com/spree/spree_social.git', :branch => '1-1-stable'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'double-bag-ftps', git: 'https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps.git'


# MailChimp
gem 'gibbon'

# Friendly URLs (for forem)
gem 'friendly_id', "4.0.9"

# ActiveRecord calls String#blank? a lot in this release
# this gem makes it faster
gem 'fast_blank'
```

Comment: Spree doesn't support any features regarding newsletter subscriptions.  Do you have an extension providing this?  If so, can you post your full Gemfile?

Comment: @gmacdougall just edited my post with Gemfile content. Can you chack it out please?